# Show the list of running processes in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

Can you suggest me a system call that retrieves the current running processes? (I have to write a **C** function like top)

I tried to read the `proc/` folder but is not good in my case.

Comment: `ps` could be the one.

Comment: Your question could be strange or ambiguous: the `system(3)` function is not a system call! And you may want to use `popen`

Comment: Why reading the `/proc/` *directory* is not good for you? And `top` is not a function, but a program....

Comment: also ps and top USE /proc ... so whatever you are doing can be done by examining /proc

Answer (score 3):

The *only* way to do that on Linux is to access the `/proc/` pseudo-file system. Remember that `/proc/` files are not "real" files on disk, so I/O (i.e. reading `/proc/` files) is quite fast.

Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page.

You could use `libprocps` which is reading `/proc/`

The `ps` and `top` (and `htop` etc...) commands are all using `/proc/`; if you want to use them from inside a program (which may be a bad idea) use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (to get their output) not [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)

So to get the running processes you could use `readdir` on `/proc/` and then read the `/proc/*/stat` files, remembering those whose status is `R` etc... etc...

Comment: Reading from the **/proc/** directory isn't necessarily the *only* way to get the current processes that are running on the system (e.g. how is **/proc/** populated); I think the OP could be asking for a kernelspace solution.

Comment: I don't understand that a system call is callable from inside the kernel. So I understood that the OP was asking from user-space point of view.

Comment: Yes I suppose you have a point, it would be an odd case for a kernel module to be invoking system calls.

Answer (score 1):

ps

ps aux

Where:

```
-A: select all processes
a: select all processes on a terminal, including those of other users
x: select processes without controlling ttys
```

Personally I like to use:

ps -ef